# Can the "conscious observer" be distinct from the "observed quantum system"?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, observers, quantum-interpretations

There speculations on the nature of consciousness by Wigner, Penrose etc., but it seems that we are nowhere close to a scientific theory of consciousness. I would like to know if the "conscious observer" could be considered distinct from the observed quantum system? If the "conscious observer" - the brain, the classical instrument that measures or some conscious entity* unknown to current physics etc. - is distinct from the observed system, then there has to be model of interaction and information transfer. If so, I would be interested to know if there is any serious paper on the nature and role of conscious observer in Quantum Physics.

Comment: Why would a “classical instrument that measures” be conscious?

Comment: @Ghoster it's an idea that was with us from the start of Quantum Mechanics, in my opinion by mistake, and it will always be something that's whispered about, by non-experts forever and perhaps even by experts. "Measurement" in its most intuitive form, for the lay person, is an action done by some conscious being that wants to measure something. "Observer" implies consciousness as well. The language QM is wrapped in, for better or for worse, invites speculation on the relationship to consciousness. I agree with you that it shouldn't imply consciousness.

Answer (score 3):

While by no means a comprehensive answer to your question, in traditional QM theories such as the Copenhagen interpretation, the conscious observer is separate from the quantum system. In other words, observers are treated as classical objects impeding on a quantum system to cause wave function collapse through some observation. As you have alluded to, though, this is by no means a very rigorous treatment since wave function collapse isn’t very well understood.

Take Eugene Wigner’s version of Schrödinger’s cat (I.e. Winger’s friend). If I have a friend who observes a quantum state, they must have collapsed the wave function, but if I don’t observe them, then for me I can consider them as having “entered” the wave function in that despite them having made an observation, for me no state has been chosen since I have no information/have not observed anything. Von Neumann proposed a similar idea in which one has a potentially infinite series of devices which make observations. One device observes the system, and then the next observes what the first device recorded, and so on, the point here being that it isn’t simple observation that collapses the wave function, but some sort of conscious observation, whatever that means. Someone has to read off from one of the devices in our chain to actually collapse the wave function.

This is one of the underlying philosophical challenges to QM if you will, mainly what is wave function collapse and what counts as an observer. People such as Hugh Everett and others have tried to give different accounts of QM to get around this. The Everett interpretation of QM for instance, otherwise known as the many worlds interpretation, essentially gets rid of wave function collapse by assuming that the wave function never collapses, but that we just live in one of those states. They are still probabilistic, but in a sense fixed for us. In this interpretation, the observer would not be distinct from the quantum system as the whole universe is our quantum system. Other interpretations try to get around these issues in other ways as well.

The overall point here is that we don’t know. In many interpretations, observers are treated as classical objects interfering with quantum systems, and thus are separate and able to cause wave function collapse. In other interpretations, it is different. While we have many ideas, as you mentioned we don’t really know very well what consciousness is, so the question of wave function collapse and observers is still quite open. I may be missing quite a bit, but hopefully at the very least this gives you some sense of how this is very much an open question.